# Activate button when other element clicked

Tags: jquery, html, button

I'm hoping this is quite simple but I'm looking to activate a specific button after I click a certain element on the page.

So far, I've looked at the button's class and added a .click function but unfortunately, this isn't working.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Note*
This button hasn't got a url contained in the link but activates a slider.

Amended Code

```
$r(document).ready(function() {

      function clickme(){
        $r('.coda-nav ul li a.current').click();  
      };

      $r('#open').click(function () {
        $r('#expandable-2').show('slow');
        clickme();
      });
       $r('#close').click(function () {
        $r('#expandable-2').hide('1000');
        clickme();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Please post some code. And what do you mean by "activate a specific button"?

Comment: With no code in your question, and with no description of what you're doing, or how you're doing it, how do you think we can provide an actual answer other than simply making guesses?

Comment: Logical Chimp has pretty much got it. I just need to click on a div element and have that activate another button within the page which in turn will scroll the slider. This other button is visible and works, I'm just adding in another way to make it slide. Please see above for current code and apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear - are you wanting to click on a Div element (for example), and have that click behave as if you have clicked on a button (or similar)?  If so, try

Edit: just seen your comment on the other answer.  Think this should do:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("#button2").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly disable the button on load then enable it when a link is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#buttonID').attr("disabled","disabled");

    $('.certainElement').click(function(e){

          $('#buttonID').removeAttr("disabled");

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7nx8M/) Fiddle:

```
// html
<button id="first">Test</button>
<br />
<button id="second" disabled>Test 2</button>​

// js
$("#first").click(function(){

   $("#second").attr("disabled", false); 

});​
```

Edit: Update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7nx8M/1/)

```
// html
<button id="first">First</button>
<br />
<button id="second">Second</button>​

// js
$("button").click(function(){

    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});


$("#first").click(function(){

   $("#second").click();

});​
```

Comment: Apologies, the button I need to activate isn't disabled, but is already clickable. I just need to be able to activate it when I use another button as well as the button assigned to the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "activate", so I've just made a button be visible, assuming it was previously hidden. Substitute the [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function for whatever you like.

```
$("#idOfOtherElement").click(function(){
    $("#idOfButton").show();
});
```